# Can you and How to serve react js or angular js without a static sever?

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, configuration, httpserver, dev-to-production

How to use the production version of a react or angular project and run without a local server? 
( like opening from index.html or something similar)

I want to make a static web application that uses react or angular 2 as a starting point. Eventually, this will be dynamic so it make sense to take advantage of either.

I don't mind using local http-serve to serve the html and css pages in development but due to some restrictions i won't be able to set up a local server or run npm start from the terminal.

I did a lot of research but never found a definitive answer as to

So like How to use the production version of a react or angular project and run without a local server? 
( like opening from index.html or something similar

Comment: You will need a web server of some sort, often `nginx` in production. What are these limitations?

Comment: Well the limitations are really configuration stuff and the users would vary significanly. The users of this app would not know how to open terminal and start the server locally but at the same time they prefer a local application for now atleast

Comment: That's possibly when you'd look at Electron. https://electron.atom.io/

Answer (score 1):

React (same as Angular) is a client-side library/framework. So all you have to do is to bundle your application to a single .js file. That file will probably include React/Angular and you may just load it in your HTML file. You definitely don't need a http-serve for that. It is possible to deploy your index.html and your bundle.js file to a shared hosting and just load the app.

Comment: When you mean bundle, do mean using wepback or some bundler or literally combine all js files into one big file? Does'nt the npm run build command do that already?  Appericiate ur answer btw

Comment: I meant to use a budler like webpack because you probably have code that need to be transpiled. Also your module imports/exports need to be resolved.